# How do I make my chatter feed in VisualForce show all posts?

Tags: visualforce, chatter, chatter-feed

I have a Chatter feed in my visualforce page and I can get the feed to show with the following code

```
<apex:page >
  <chatter:feed entityId="{!$User.Id}"/>
</apex:page>
```

However this only displays my posts and comments.  I want to display all the posts that the people I follow post. How do I do this?  Or the entire Organisations posts. FYI - I don't have a controller for this page.

Thanks

Comment: did you try `chatter:feedWithFollowers`?

Comment: Thanks Santanu Just tried it but it did the same thing, but with a div with my followers in it.  The feed remains the same with just my posts, comments . Do I need to change the entityID ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, the answer is chatter:newsfeed

```
<chatter:newsfeed />
```

Comment: you should accept your answer after 2 days, so that others might get benefited.